# simple image encryption before uploading to parse

Tags: java, android, parsing, encryption

I have an application that takes a *photo* from a `camera intent` and uploads to a parse server and when the application opens it loads all images from parse and mark them on the map basically **what I'm looking for is, as an administrator in parse server I am able to see the content of all images. So I was wondering if there is a simple way to encrypt these images before uploading them so that when they get uploaded I don't get to see them as an admin** (I'm not looking for high security just way to hide them from the admin). Here is my upload code

```
public void takePicture(View view) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode){


        // in case of capturing image using camera
        case (100):
        {
            if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                // reduce image size so it fits inside imageview

                int targetImageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
                int targetImageViewHeight =imageView.getHeight();

                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);
                int cameraImageWidth = bmOptions.outWidth;
                int cameraImageHeight = bmOptions.outHeight;

                int scaleFactor= Math.min(cameraImageWidth/targetImageViewWidth,cameraImageHeight/targetImageViewHeight);
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                // replacing the imageview with taken picture after scaling it down

                Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);

                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.png", byteArray);

                    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("Image");

                    object.put("image", file);
                    object.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                    object.put("location", new ParseGeoPoint(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseGeoPoint("location")));
```

Comment: "the application opens " is on the server? Why not just upload the location? Encryption implies the server and decrypt ad that implies the decryption key is available on the server and an admin has access to the key and thus the images.

Comment: @zaph that is true i understand what are u saying but i just want away to prevent the admin from accessing the images directly from the control panel so i thought of encrypting is there any other ways to prevent that from happening ?